# Laravel: How can I return an array within a collection?

Tags: laravel-5.3

I am requesting all of an athletes data from an api call like this and everything is coming across great.

**MyController.php**

```
public function get($year, $position_id)
{
    $collection = collect(
        $athletes = Athlete::where('athletes.graduation_year', $year)
            ->join('athlete_position', 'athlete_position.athlete_id', '=', 'athletes.id')
            ->where('athlete_position.position_id', '=', $position_id)
            ->join('evaluations', 'evaluations.athlete_id', 'athletes.id')
            ->whereNotNull('evaluations.comments')
            ->where('evaluations.status', 'published')
            ->orderBy('rank', 'asc')
            ->orderBy('rating', 'asc')
            ->orderBy('last_name', 'asc')
            ->get()
    )->groupBy('rating');

    return response()->json(['data' => $collection], 200);
}
```

I would now like to add my offers table to this join:

```
...
->join('evaluations', 'evaluations.athlete_id', 'athletes.craft_id')
->whereNotNull('evaluations.comments')
->where('evaluations.status', 'published')
->join('offers', 'offers.athlete_id', 'athletes.craft_id')
...
```

Which works, but now I am getting duplicate athletes; one for each offer. For example, if an athlete has three offers, I'll get the same athlete back three times - once for each offer.

What I would like is an array of offers within the collection. Something like looks like this:

```
$athlete {
    ...
    'evaluation': '<p>My evaluation...</p>',
    'offers': [
        {'school': '<p>Clemson</p>','committed': 1},
        {'school': '<p>Alabama</p>', 'committed': 0} 
    ]
    ...
 }
```

This way I only get one record for each athlete, but each athlete can have many offers.

My models look like this:

**Athlete.php**

```
public function offers()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Offer');
}
```

**Offer.php**

```
public function athletes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Athlete');
}
```

All of the data is returned properly throughout my application - it's just the API call is where I'm struggling.

Thank you for any suggestions!

**EDIT**

Here is what my select looks like now:

```
$collection = collect(
        $athletes = DB::table('athletes')->select('craft_id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'high_school_state', 'graduation_year', 'rank', 'rating', 'evaluations.comments', 'offers.school')
            ->where('athletes.graduation_year', $year)
            ->join('athlete_position', 'athlete_position.athlete_id', '=', 'athletes.craft_id')
            ->where('athlete_position.position_id', '=', $position_id)
            ->join('evaluations', 'evaluations.athlete_id', 'athletes.craft_id')
            ->whereNotNull('evaluations.comments')
            ->where('evaluations.status', 'published')
            ->join('offers', 'offers.athlete_id', 'athletes.craft_id')
            ->orderBy('rank', 'asc')
            ->orderBy('rating', 'asc')
            ->orderBy('last_name', 'asc')
            ->get()
    )->groupBy('rating');
```

It's returning the data, If I have more than one offer, instead of getting the offers as an array, I get two complete records back.

```
"data": {
    ...
  {
    "first_name": "Tyler",
    "last_name": "Durden",
    "offers":  "Clemson"
  },
   {
    "first_name": "Tyler",
    "last_name": "Durden",
    "offers":  "Alabama"
  },
```

I'm trying to get:

```
"data": {
...
  {
    "first_name": "Tyler",
    "last_name": "Durden",
    "offers":  [
        "school": "Clemson"
        "school": "Alabama"
    ]
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

With such complex queries are best used method

```
->select('athletes.*') etc
```

that will save you from duplicating

[documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#selects)

Comment: I don't think I follow. I've updated my question to try and show what I've changed to try your suggestion.